# Cannot get rid of one-pixel-wide white margins (bottom and right side) of plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot and save my matrix using `image()` with no axes,labels,margins, etc. What I need is just pure colored image where the number of cells will correspond to number of pixels on saved plot. On R graphics device it looks fine, but if I save the plot to the file then there always persist one pixel wide white margins on the bottom and right side of the image. I tried all formats but did not succeed. I am using GIMP for image manipulation.

Example code:

```
png("heatmap.png",w=400,h=400)
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
require(grDevices) # for colours
x <- y <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len=400)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))
image(z = z <- cos(r^2)*exp(-r/6), col=gray((0:32)/32),axes = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Seems like this is bug report worthy.

Comment: @Thomas but the bug *could* be in the `WindowsGDI` device driver? (I'm assuming you meant filing a bug report for R core)

Answer (score 7):

I'm gonna go ahead and assume you are on Windows. `png` seems to use the `WindowsGDI` device to plot by default. Use cairographics instead, by setting `type = "cario"`...

```
png("heatmap.png",w=400,h=400 , type="cairo" )
```

[image]

The border disappears. The answer as to why this occurs with the `WindowsGDI` device is likely to be found on the [`grDevices::windows`](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/grDevices/html/windows.html) help page...

Comment: +1 - this option is more generally applicable - The `useRaster=TRUE` option requires that "The grid must be regular...".

Comment: @Marcinthebox thanks but strange behaviour from the WindowsGDI device anyway.

Answer (score 3):

By using the argument `useRaster=TRUE` , the problem is resolved:

```
png("heatmap.png",w=400,h=400)
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
require(grDevices) # for colours
x <- y <- seq(-4*pi, 4*pi, len=400)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))
z <- cos(r^2)*exp(-r/6)
image(z, col=gray((0:32)/32), axes=FALSE, useRaster=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

[image]