# draw border around legend continuous gradient color bar of heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to add a border around the continuous gradient color bar. By default, ggplot picks up the fill color specified in the `scale_fill_gradient`.

The closest answer, I found is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793398/adding-border-or-background-to-scale-legend-guide-colorbar-in-ggplot2), but it did not help me with this task.

I also tried this with legend key, but did not help me.

```
legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 4)
```

Please see the current and expected graphs below.

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(go = structure(c(17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 
                                       11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 
                                       14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
                                       17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
                                       3L, 2L, 1L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
                                       6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), 
                                     .Label = c("q", "p", "o", "n", "m", "l", "k", "j", "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"), 
                                     class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
                      variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                             4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                                           class = "factor", .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d")),
                      value = c(-0.626453810742332, 0.183643324222082, -0.835628612410047, 1.59528080213779, 0.329507771815361, 
                                -0.820468384118015, 0.487429052428485, 0.738324705129217, 0.575781351653492, 
                                -0.305388387156356, 1.51178116845085, 0.389843236411431, -0.621240580541804, 
                                -2.2146998871775, 1.12493091814311, -0.0449336090152309, -0.0161902630989461, 
                                0.943836210685299, 0.821221195098089, 0.593901321217509, 0.918977371608218, 
                                0.782136300731067, 0.0745649833651906, -1.98935169586337, 0.61982574789471, 
                                -0.0561287395290008, -0.155795506705329, -1.47075238389927, -0.47815005510862, 
                                0.417941560199702, 1.35867955152904, -0.102787727342996, 0.387671611559369, 
                                -0.0538050405829051, -1.37705955682861, -0.41499456329968, -0.394289953710349, 
                                -0.0593133967111857, 1.10002537198388, 0.763175748457544, -0.164523596253587, 
                                -0.253361680136508, 0.696963375404737, 0.556663198673657, -0.68875569454952, 
                                -0.70749515696212, 0.36458196213683, 0.768532924515416, -0.112346212150228, 
                                0.881107726454215, 0.398105880367068, -0.612026393250771, 0.341119691424425, 
                                -1.12936309608079, 1.43302370170104, 1.98039989850586, -0.367221476466509, 
                                -1.04413462631653, 0.569719627442413, -0.135054603880824, 2.40161776050478, 
                                -0.0392400027331692, 0.689739362450777, 0.0280021587806661, -0.743273208882405, 
                                0.188792299514343, -1.80495862889104, 1.46555486156289)), 
                 .Names = c("go", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -68L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot( data = df1, mapping = aes( x = variable, y = go ) ) +  # draw heatmap
  geom_tile( aes( fill = value ),  colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient( low = "white", high = "black",
                       guide = guide_colorbar(label = TRUE,
                                              draw.ulim = TRUE, 
                                              draw.llim = TRUE,
                                              ticks = TRUE, 
                                              nbin = 10,
                                              label.position = "bottom",
                                              barwidth = 13,
                                              barheight = 1.3, 
                                              direction = 'horizontal')) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 4)
  )
```

**Current Graph:**

[image]

**Expected Graph:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a chance to make the edges of a colorbar round?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is now possible in the github version of ggplot2, as of May 2, 2018, and will be part of ggplot2 2.3:

```
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2") # do this once, to install github version
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( data = df1, mapping = aes( x = variable, y = go ) ) +  # draw heatmap
  geom_tile( aes( fill = value ),  colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient( low = "white", high = "black",
                       guide = guide_colorbar(label = TRUE,
                                              draw.ulim = TRUE, 
                                              draw.llim = TRUE,
                                           # here comes the code change:
                                              frame.colour = "black",
                                              ticks = TRUE, 
                                              nbin = 10,
                                              label.position = "bottom",
                                              barwidth = 13,
                                              barheight = 1.3, 
                                              direction = 'horizontal')) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Specifically, the following arguments were added to `guide_colorbar()`:

- `frame.colour` The color of the frame around the colorbar. If `NULL`, no frame is drawn.
- `frame.linewidth` The line width of the frame.
- `frame.linetype` The line type of the frame.
- `ticks.colour` The color of the tick lines that are drawn.
- `ticks.linewidth` The width of the tick lines.

These five arguments should allow for the most commonly requested stylings. More sophisticated stylings (such as tick lines outside) will require a general rethinking of how the guides are themed, in my opinion.

Comment: FYI for anyone used to "colour" and "color" being interchangeable in ggplot2, it is not so in this case.  You must use "frame.colour" and "ticks.colour" and not "frame.color", "ticks.color".

Answer (score 6):

**Update: This answer is now obsolete. Use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144362/4975218) instead. I'm leaving the obsolete answer only because the same principle works for other problems.**

The ggplot2 legend drawing code is a bit of a mess and not very customizable. The only way I see to get this effect is to make a modification to `guide_colorbar()`. Unfortunately, this requires copying a lot of ggplot2 code.

I'm currently running the development version of ggplot2, so the exact code I'll be posting is only guaranteed to run with that. (I'm using what is on github as of today, 4/27/2018). But the principle will work with the released version as well.

First the plotting code once we have defined our new legend function:

```
ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = variable, y = go)) +  # draw heatmap
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),  colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black",
                      guide = guide_colorbar2(label = TRUE,
                                              draw.ulim = TRUE, 
                                              draw.llim = TRUE,
                                              ticks = TRUE, 
                                              nbin = 10,
                                              label.position = "bottom",
                                              barwidth = 13,
                                              barheight = 1.3, 
                                              direction = 'horizontal')) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 4),
        # the following corresponds to 4pt due to current bug
        # in legend code; this will hopefully be fixed before
        # the next ggplot2 release
        legend.spacing.y = grid::unit(40, "pt")
  )
```

There are two changes to your code. I wrote `guide_colorbar2` instead of `guide_colorbar`, and I added a `legend.spacing.y` line in the theme code to move the labels away from the colorbar. The result is the following:

[image]

Now the copied colorbar code. This is mostly a verbatim copy from ggplot2. For all internal ggplot2 functions that are being used, we have to prepend `ggplot:::` to the function call, e.g. `ggplot2:::width_cm` instead of `width_cm`. The actual change that draws the outline is only two additional lines of code, and it is clearly marked with comments.

```
# the code below uses functions from these libraries
library(rlang)
library(grid)
library(gtable)
library(scales)

# this is a verbatim copy, with colorbar replaced by colorbar2
# (note also the class statement at the very end of this function) 
guide_colorbar2 <- function(

  # title
  title = waiver(),
  title.position = NULL,
  title.theme = NULL,
  title.hjust = NULL,
  title.vjust = NULL,

  # label
  label = TRUE,
  label.position = NULL,
  label.theme = NULL,
  label.hjust = NULL,
  label.vjust = NULL,

  # bar
  barwidth = NULL,
  barheight = NULL,
  nbin = 20,
  raster = TRUE,

  # ticks
  ticks = TRUE,
  draw.ulim= TRUE,
  draw.llim = TRUE,

  # general
  direction = NULL,
  default.unit = "line",
  reverse = FALSE,
  order = 0,

  ...) {

  if (!is.null(barwidth) && !is.unit(barwidth)) barwidth <- unit(barwidth, default.unit)
  if (!is.null(barheight) && !is.unit(barheight)) barheight <- unit(barheight, default.unit)

  structure(list(
    # title
    title = title,
    title.position = title.position,
    title.theme = title.theme,
    title.hjust = title.hjust,
    title.vjust = title.vjust,

    # label
    label = label,
    label.position = label.position,
    label.theme = label.theme,
    label.hjust = label.hjust,
    label.vjust = label.vjust,

    # bar
    barwidth = barwidth,
    barheight = barheight,
    nbin = nbin,
    raster = raster,

    # ticks
    ticks = ticks,
    draw.ulim = draw.ulim,
    draw.llim = draw.llim,

    # general
    direction = direction,
    default.unit = default.unit,
    reverse = reverse,
    order = order,

    # parameter
    available_aes = c("colour", "color", "fill"), ..., name = "colorbar"),
    class = c("guide", "colorbar2")
  )
}

# this saves us from copying the code over. Just call the ggplot2
# version of the function
guide_train.colorbar2 <- function(...) {
  ggplot2:::guide_train.colorbar(...)
}

# this saves us from copying the code over. Just call the ggplot2
# version of the function    
guide_merge.colorbar2 <- function(...) {
  ggplot2:::guide_merge.colorbar(...)
}

# this saves us from copying the code over. Just call the ggplot2
# version of the function
guide_geom.colorbar2 <- function(...) {
  ggplot2:::guide_geom.colorbar(...)
}

# this is the function that does the actual legend drawing
# and that we have to modify
guide_gengrob.colorbar2 <- function(guide, theme) {
  # settings of location and size
  switch(guide$direction,
         "horizontal" = {
           label.position <- guide$label.position %||% "bottom"
           if (!label.position %in% c("top", "bottom")) stop("label position \"", label.position, "\" is invalid")

           barwidth <- convertWidth(guide$barwidth %||% (theme$legend.key.width * 5), "mm")
           barheight <- convertHeight(guide$barheight %||% theme$legend.key.height, "mm")
         },
         "vertical" = {
           label.position <- guide$label.position %||% "right"
           if (!label.position %in% c("left", "right")) stop("label position \"", label.position, "\" is invalid")

           barwidth <- convertWidth(guide$barwidth %||% theme$legend.key.width, "mm")
           barheight <- convertHeight(guide$barheight %||% (theme$legend.key.height * 5), "mm")
         })

  barwidth.c <- c(barwidth)
  barheight.c <- c(barheight)
  barlength.c <- switch(guide$direction, "horizontal" = barwidth.c, "vertical" = barheight.c)
  nbreak <- nrow(guide$key)

  grob.bar <-
    if (guide$raster) {
      image <- switch(guide$direction, horizontal = t(guide$bar$colour), vertical = rev(guide$bar$colour))
      rasterGrob(image = image, width = barwidth.c, height = barheight.c, default.units = "mm", gp = gpar(col = NA), interpolate = TRUE)
    } else {
      switch(guide$direction,
             horizontal = {
               bw <- barwidth.c / nrow(guide$bar)
               bx <- (seq(nrow(guide$bar)) - 1) * bw
               rectGrob(x = bx, y = 0, vjust = 0, hjust = 0, width = bw, height = barheight.c, default.units = "mm",
                        gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = guide$bar$colour))
             },
             vertical = {
               bh <- barheight.c / nrow(guide$bar)
               by <- (seq(nrow(guide$bar)) - 1) * bh
               rectGrob(x = 0, y = by, vjust = 0, hjust = 0, width = barwidth.c, height = bh, default.units = "mm",
                        gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = guide$bar$colour))
             })
    }

  # ********************************************************
  # here is the change to draw a border around the color bar
  grob.bar <- grobTree(grob.bar, 
    rectGrob(width = barwidth.c, height = barheight.c, default.units = "mm", gp = gpar(col = "black", fill = NA)))
  # ********************************************************

  # tick and label position
  tic_pos.c <- rescale(guide$key$.value, c(0.5, guide$nbin - 0.5), guide$bar$value[c(1, nrow(guide$bar))]) * barlength.c / guide$nbin
  label_pos <- unit(tic_pos.c, "mm")
  if (!guide$draw.ulim) tic_pos.c <- tic_pos.c[-1]
  if (!guide$draw.llim) tic_pos.c <- tic_pos.c[-length(tic_pos.c)]

  # title
  grob.title <- ggplot2:::ggname("guide.title",
                       element_grob(
                         guide$title.theme %||% calc_element("legend.title", theme),
                         label = guide$title,
                         hjust = guide$title.hjust %||% theme$legend.title.align %||% 0,
                         vjust = guide$title.vjust %||% 0.5
                       )
  )


  title_width <- convertWidth(grobWidth(grob.title), "mm")
  title_width.c <- c(title_width)
  title_height <- convertHeight(grobHeight(grob.title), "mm")
  title_height.c <- c(title_height)

  # gap between keys etc
  hgap <- ggplot2:::width_cm(theme$legend.spacing.x  %||% unit(0.3, "line"))
  vgap <- ggplot2:::height_cm(theme$legend.spacing.y %||% (0.5 * unit(title_height, "cm")))

  # label
  label.theme <- guide$label.theme %||% calc_element("legend.text", theme)
  grob.label <- {
    if (!guide$label)
      zeroGrob()
    else {
      hjust <- x <- guide$label.hjust %||% theme$legend.text.align %||%
        if (any(is.expression(guide$key$.label))) 1 else switch(guide$direction, horizontal = 0.5, vertical = 0)
      vjust <- y <- guide$label.vjust %||% 0.5
      switch(guide$direction, horizontal = {x <- label_pos; y <- vjust}, "vertical" = {x <- hjust; y <- label_pos})

      label <- guide$key$.label

      # If any of the labels are quoted language objects, convert them
      # to expressions. Labels from formatter functions can return these
      if (any(vapply(label, is.call, logical(1)))) {
        label <- lapply(label, function(l) {
          if (is.call(l)) substitute(expression(x), list(x = l))
          else l
        })
        label <- do.call(c, label)
      }
      g <- element_grob(element = label.theme, label = label,
                        x = x, y = y, hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust)
      ggplot2:::ggname("guide.label", g)
    }
  }

  label_width <- convertWidth(grobWidth(grob.label), "mm")
  label_width.c <- c(label_width)
  label_height <- convertHeight(grobHeight(grob.label), "mm")
  label_height.c <- c(label_height)

  # ticks
  grob.ticks <-
    if (!guide$ticks) zeroGrob()
  else {
    switch(guide$direction,
           "horizontal" = {
             x0 = rep(tic_pos.c, 2)
             y0 = c(rep(0, nbreak), rep(barheight.c * (4/5), nbreak))
             x1 = rep(tic_pos.c, 2)
             y1 = c(rep(barheight.c * (1/5), nbreak), rep(barheight.c, nbreak))
           },
           "vertical" = {
             x0 = c(rep(0, nbreak), rep(barwidth.c * (4/5), nbreak))
             y0 = rep(tic_pos.c, 2)
             x1 = c(rep(barwidth.c * (1/5), nbreak), rep(barwidth.c, nbreak))
             y1 = rep(tic_pos.c, 2)
           })
    segmentsGrob(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, x1 = x1, y1 = y1,
                 default.units = "mm", gp = gpar(col = "white", lwd = 0.5, lineend = "butt"))
  }

  # layout of bar and label
  switch(guide$direction,
         "horizontal" = {
           switch(label.position,
                  "top" = {
                    bl_widths <- barwidth.c
                    bl_heights <- c(label_height.c, vgap, barheight.c)
                    vps <- list(bar.row = 3, bar.col = 1,
                                label.row = 1, label.col = 1)
                  },
                  "bottom" = {
                    bl_widths <- barwidth.c
                    bl_heights <- c(barheight.c, vgap, label_height.c)
                    vps <- list(bar.row = 1, bar.col = 1,
                                label.row = 3, label.col = 1)
                  })
         },
         "vertical" = {
           switch(label.position,
                  "left" = {
                    bl_widths <- c(label_width.c, vgap, barwidth.c)
                    bl_heights <- barheight.c
                    vps <- list(bar.row = 1, bar.col = 3,
                                label.row = 1, label.col = 1)
                  },
                  "right" = {
                    bl_widths <- c(barwidth.c, vgap, label_width.c)
                    bl_heights <- barheight.c
                    vps <- list(bar.row = 1, bar.col = 1,
                                label.row = 1, label.col = 3)
                  })
         })

  # layout of title and bar+label
  switch(guide$title.position,
         "top" = {
           widths <- c(bl_widths, max(0, title_width.c - sum(bl_widths)))
           heights <- c(title_height.c, vgap, bl_heights)
           vps <- with(vps,
                       list(bar.row = bar.row + 2, bar.col = bar.col,
                            label.row = label.row + 2, label.col = label.col,
                            title.row = 1, title.col = 1:length(widths)))
         },
         "bottom" = {
           widths <- c(bl_widths, max(0, title_width.c - sum(bl_widths)))
           heights <- c(bl_heights, vgap, title_height.c)
           vps <- with(vps,
                       list(bar.row = bar.row, bar.col = bar.col,
                            label.row = label.row, label.col = label.col,
                            title.row = length(heights), title.col = 1:length(widths)))
         },
         "left" = {
           widths <- c(title_width.c, hgap, bl_widths)
           heights <- c(bl_heights, max(0, title_height.c - sum(bl_heights)))
           vps <- with(vps,
                       list(bar.row = bar.row, bar.col = bar.col + 2,
                            label.row = label.row, label.col = label.col + 2,
                            title.row = 1:length(heights), title.col = 1))
         },
         "right" = {
           widths <- c(bl_widths, hgap, title_width.c)
           heights <- c(bl_heights, max(0, title_height.c - sum(bl_heights)))
           vps <- with(vps,
                       list(bar.row = bar.row, bar.col = bar.col,
                            label.row = label.row, label.col = label.col,
                            title.row = 1:length(heights), title.col = length(widths)))
         })

  # background
  grob.background <- ggplot2:::element_render(theme, "legend.background")

  # padding
  padding <- convertUnit(theme$legend.margin %||% margin(), "mm")
  widths <- c(padding[4], widths, padding[2])
  heights <- c(padding[1], heights, padding[3])

  gt <- gtable(widths = unit(widths, "mm"), heights = unit(heights, "mm"))
  gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, grob.background, name = "background", clip = "off",
                        t = 1, r = -1, b = -1, l = 1)
  gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, grob.bar, name = "bar", clip = "off",
                        t = 1 + min(vps$bar.row), r = 1 + max(vps$bar.col),
                        b = 1 + max(vps$bar.row), l = 1 + min(vps$bar.col))
  gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, grob.label, name = "label", clip = "off",
                        t = 1 + min(vps$label.row), r = 1 + max(vps$label.col),
                        b = 1 + max(vps$label.row), l = 1 + min(vps$label.col))
  gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, grob.title, name = "title", clip = "off",
                        t = 1 + min(vps$title.row), r = 1 + max(vps$title.col),
                        b = 1 + max(vps$title.row), l = 1 + min(vps$title.col))
  gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, grob.ticks, name = "ticks", clip = "off",
                        t = 1 + min(vps$bar.row), r = 1 + max(vps$bar.col),
                        b = 1 + max(vps$bar.row), l = 1 + min(vps$bar.col))

  gt
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can do it automatically but here is a manual way to draw the box using `grid.rect`. You can change `x`, `y`, `width` or `height` to suit your needs

```
library(grid)
grid.rect(x= 0.5, y = 0.075, width = 0.355, height = 0.05, 
          gp = gpar(lwd = 1, col = "black", fill = NA))
```

[image]

Looking at `ggplot2` source code, I guess you could possibly modify [`draw_key_rect`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/legend-draw.r#L44) to get the border color

```
draw_key_rect <- function(data, params, size) {
  rectGrob(gp = gpar(
    col = NA,
    fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
    lty = data$linetype
  ))
}
```

Created on 2018-04-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).